# why unknown charactor added to value in mysql table when trying to insert a value in Pound (£9000)

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm trying  add a value in Pound to my table in mysql `(eg: £9000)`, 
In the table field shows like `Â£9000`. 
I tried by changing the `Collation` value to `utf8_unicode_ci`.
But the result is same an extra character is added to field.
Is there any method to remove it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 While this is generally true, it won't help at all in this situation. This is clearly an encoding/charset issue, not a quoting issue.

Answer (score 2):

The connection between your php instance and the mysql server has a character set associated to it. The mysql server expects the data send by your php script to be encoded in that charset. Apparently your php script sends utf-8 encoded data while the server expects something like iso-8859 (or similar) and hence interprets the two bytes coding for £ in utf-8 as two separate characters.
You should change the connection charset to utf-8, e.g. by using php >= 5.3.6, pdo and `charset=utf8` appended to the dns.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html
and http://docs.php.net/ref.pdo-mysql.connection